# How to print source node in graph?

Tags: graph, stl

I created undirected graph using stl .the output of this program like:

1 2

0 2

0 1

but I want to print source node also ::output should be:

0 1 2

1 0 2

2 0 1

what should I do in code ?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
vector <list<int> >a(4);
void addEdge(int i,int j)
{
  a[i].push_back(j);
  a[j].push_back(i);
}
int main()
{
    vector<list<int> >::iterator it1=a.begin();
    addEdge(0,1);
    addEdge(0,2);
    addEdge(1,2);

    int i=0;
    while(it1!=a.end())

   {

    list<int> it2=*it1;
    list<int>::iterator itr=it2.begin();

    while(itr!=it2.end())
    {
        cout<<*itr<<" ";
        itr++;
    }
    cout<<endl;
    it1++;
  }
}
```

Comment: What do u exactly mean by 'source node'? your example isn't very clear. Your graph is a triangle. I see you are storing your graph as an adjacency list... but I don't understand what you actually want to output

Comment: The source node would be `it1 - a.begin()`, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: i want to print source node in output but am unable to print .i'm beginner in stl  .                                                                                                                             0->1->2 here source node is 0 .my code only print the  1-->2

Comment: Oh I see, you want to output the node on which you have your list attached to. Well, then you have to do as @IgorTandetnik said and just `cout << it1 - a.begin() << " ";` before the `while(itr!=it2.end())`.

Comment: thank you @dingalapadum and @ IgorTandetnik .